# Can I use vue.js v-if to check is the value exists in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have checkbox in form and I would like to use v-if directly to show/hide sections in accordance of selected checkbox values.

Is it possible or I should use watch: ?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: works until two or more is selected

Comment: @rpz There are many ***possible*** answers.  Please post a small, concise code example so that we can help you find the ***right*** answer.

Comment: I created the fiddle with watch expression, any thoughts how to avoid watch: and do it directly in v-if?  https://jsfiddle.net/w6svt1w7/5/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is possible. I would recommend adding a data model to the checkbox that toggles true or false. Then that will allow you to toggle the appearance of content using `v-if`.

Example:

```
<template>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="showContent" value="triggerString" />
    <p v-if="showContent === 'triggerString'">Lorem ipsum</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                showContent: false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Generally speaking, we try not to use `watch` when we don't have to.

**Update**: Using the JSFiddle you included, this is how you would do it with just `v-if`

```
<template>
    <input type="checkbox" 
           v-model="section"
           name="section"
           value="Epiphone"
           id="epiphone">
    <label for="epiphone">Epiphone</label>

    <section v-if="section.includes('Epiphone')">
        <h1>Epiphone</h1>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                section: []
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Since there is two way binding occurring on the section array you created, there is no need for an additional `div` object since the only tracking that will occur will be in the section object.

The key thing to remember about `v-if` is that it can take actual JS expressions in it and not just data values. So you can extract out the logic from your watch method and simply plug it in there.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: thank you. What if showContent is an array that has two values ['apple','orange]. Would it be possible to check with v-if that apple is in array? 

I am working with long forms and would like to cut the code as much as possible but at the same time I am newbie, much to learn..

Comment: @rpz Yes. You can use the indexOf property on the array to return true or false based on whether the index is greater than -1.

Comment: @rpz I've updated the answer with a sample from your JSFiddle

Comment: this helped me thank you `<section v-if="section.includes('Epiphone')">`